# When I click a number close to the empty box, it should move (Beginner)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm pretty new too this and were wondering if somebody could help me with this "easy" tricky code, the thing is I want the numbers too move like a picture puzzle, soo when you click a number away from the empty box nothing happens but when you click a number beside it, the number will move to the location of the empty box and the box wil move to the number's last location. This is what I have so far :P

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <Style>
        div.container {
            display: flex;
            height: 28vh;
        }
        div.BundTekst {
            display: flex;
            height: 28vh;
        }
        div.number {
            color: White;
            background-color: black;
            margin: 10px;
            border: 10px solid red;
            display: flex;
            flex: 1;
            font-size: 500%;
            text-align: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Introduksjon til HTML, CSS og Javascript</h1>

    <div class="container"> 
        <div id="A1" class="number" onclick="show(this)" >7</div>
        <div id="A2" class="number" onclick="show(this)" >2</div>
        <div id="A3" class="number" onclick="show(this)" >5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="B1" class="number" onclick="show(this)" >1</div>
        <div id="B2" class="number" onclick="show(this)" ></div>
        <div id="B3" class="number" onclick="show(this)" >3</div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="container">
        <div id="C1" class="number" onclick="show(this)" >6</div>
        <div id="C2" class="number" onclick="show(this)" >9</div>
        <div id="C3" class="number" onclick="show(this)" >8</div>
    </div>
  
    <script>
        var counter = 0;
        var lastClickedDiv;

        function show(tag, alt1, alt2, alt3, alt4){ 
            if(alt1 && document.getElementById(alt2).innerHTML == 'Alt1')
            {
                tag.innerHTML = 'alt1';
            }
            if(alt2 && document.getElementById(alt2).innerHTML == 'alt2')
            {
                tag.innerHTML = 'alt2';
            }
            if(alt3 && document.getElementById(alt3).innerHTML == 'alt3')
            {
                tag.innerHTML = 'Alt3';
            }
            if(alt4 && document.getElementById(alt4).innerHTML == 'alt4')
            {
                tag.innerHTML = 'Alt3';
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: syntax error to run code snippet

Comment: By "move", do you mean an animation?

Comment: In your function `show` you define 5 parameters. You always call it with one argument. This is certainly not a problem in JavaScript, but what is your point here?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code. Hope this is what you are looking for:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        div.container {
            display: flex;
            height: 28vh;
        }
        div.BundTekst {
            display: flex;
            height: 28vh;
        }
        div.number {
            color: White;
            background-color: black;
            margin: 10px;
            border: 10px solid red;
            display: flex;
            flex: 1;
            font-size: 500%;
            text-align: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Introduksjon til HTML, CSS og Javascript</h1>

    <div class="container"> 
        <div id="A1" class="number">7</div>
        <div id="A2" class="number">2</div>
        <div id="A3" class="number">5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="B1" class="number">1</div>
        <div id="B2" class="number empty"></div>
        <div id="B3" class="number">3</div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="container">
        <div id="C1" class="number">6</div>
        <div id="C2" class="number">9</div>
        <div id="C3" class="number">8</div>
    </div>
  
    <script>
        $(".number").click(function(){
          $(".empty").text($(this).text()).removeClass('empty');
          $(this).addClass('active').text('').addClass('empty');
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```